# Problems with discovering modules inside metaclass's __new__

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

Basically, I want to load all functions of a specific module (if it exists) and merge them with the class methods. If I had the `__module__` of the class that is being built inside `__new__` I could build the path straight to the module and import it. I'm looking for a `get_module_fns` to solve my problem. I wish to do something like:

```
get_module_fns('pathto.mod1.toimport')
```

and if it exists, it will return all functions as a dict.

Here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghu5duznwl140uc/stackoverflow.zip?dl=0) for the code and tests.

```
# mtcl.py
import inspect
import imp


def get_module_fns(module_name, module_path):
    try:
        mod_loaded = imp.load_source(module_name, module_path)
        module_fns = [(name, func) for name, func in
                      inspect.getmembers(mod_loaded, inspect.isfunction)]
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        return {}
    except ImportError as e:
        return {}
    return dict(module_fns)


class GetModuleFunctions(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespaces, **kwargs):

        module_functions = get_module_fns('toimport', './toimport.py')
        namespaces.update(module_functions)

        new_class = super(GetModuleFunctions, cls).__new__(
            cls, name, bases, namespaces)

        new_class._mdl_fns = module_functions

        return new_class


class ClassBase(metaclass=GetModuleFunctions):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def module_functions(self):
        return self.__class__._mdl_fns
```

```
# mod0.py
from .mtcl import ClassBase


class M0(ClassBase):

    def function_m0(self):
        return 0
```

```
# mod1/__init__.py
from ..mtcl import ClassBase


class M1(ClassBase):

    def function_m1(self):
        return 1
```

```
# mod1/toimport.py

def function_1(obj,  *args, **kwargs):
    return 1
```

```
# mod1/mod2/__init__.py
from ...mtcl import ClassBase


class M2(ClassBase):

    def function_m2(self):
        return 2
```

```
# mod1/mod2/toimport.py

def function_2(obj,  *args, **kwargs):
    return 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import inspect
import importlib


def get_module_fns(cls, module_name):
    try:
        mod_loaded = importlib.import_module(
            '%s.%s' % (cls.__module__, module_name)
        )
        module_fns = [(name, func) for name, func in
                      inspect.getmembers(mod_loaded, inspect.isfunction)]
    except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
        return {}
    except ImportError as e:
        return {}
    return dict(module_fns)


class GetModuleFunctions(type):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_class = super(GetModuleFunctions, cls).__new__(
            cls, *args, **kwargs)
        module_functions = get_module_fns(new_class, 'toimport')
        for name, fn in module_functions.items():
            setattr(new_class, name, fn)
        new_class._mdl_fns = module_functions
        return new_class
```

Since you're looking for a module within your class' module, this should do it:

```
mod_loaded = importlib.import_module(
    '%s.%s' % (cls.__module__, module_name)
)
```

Sadly, you can't use `namespace` after `__new__.super`:

```
for name, fn in module_functions.items():                
    setattr(new_class, name, fn)
```